# How to get application BETA version of apk in Google play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, developer-console

I use CI and CD to deploy my Apps on gplay. Prod and beta versions.

After you send your apk to gplay there is a time delay(~4hour) until your application will be available for download. 
And when it's available I need custom notification about it.
For production version I have timer scheduler that parse gplay html and retrieve app version.

But how to find the version number for the beta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found only one solution for this.
In your developer console you have notification options for email - enable it.
And you will get email notification when your beta apk available on gplay for beta testers. If you parse this email and trigger it on your backend, you can make your own custom notification.